# Как лучше всего разграничить доступ к данным между пользователями?

Tags: безопасность

**Задача:** имеется многопользовательское web-приложение. Все ресурсы в этом приложении имеют глобально-уникальные ID (т.е. каждый ресурс можно однозначно идентифицировать среди всех ресурсов всех пользователей). Тип идентификаторов - UUID.
Необходимо чтобы доступ к ресурсу мог получить только его владелец.

**Как я пытался решить задачу:** сейчас я рассматриваю два подхода:

1. если для получения доступа к ресурсу достаточно знать только его ID - то любой пользователь сможет получить доступ к ресурсу любого другого пользователя даже не зная учетных данных последнего. Поэтому нужно проверять - является ли данный пользователь владельцем ресурса. Для этого, помимо ID ресурса, нужно брать ещё и ID пользователя. Важно - ID пользователя НЕ указывается прямо в параметрах запроса, а зашит внутри токена доступа (JWS).
2. идентификаторы ресурсов имеют тип UUID, и подобрать такой ID - задача очень не простая (даже если пытаться получить доступ не к конкретному ресурсу, а к случайному). Поэтому дополнительные меры предосторожности излишни и просто усложнят код. Если тип идентификаторов ресурсов - это UUID, то вполне безопасно получать доступ к ресурсу зная только его ID.

**Вопрос:** какой из двух подходов лучше с точки зрения безопасности и почему?

Comment: Пользователю доверять нельзя. Поэтому очевидно, что второй вариант идёт гулять

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что пользователь может сам спалить ID своего ресурса?

Comment: Ссылка может утечь тысячью способов

Comment: Второй подход это типичный [Security through obscurity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) с всеми его минусами, так что первый лучше.